# Observed conditional probabilities significance

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have some initial expected conditional probabilities distribution. Let's say for  a single event expected: $P(B|A) = p$. Now I'm collecting some data and see that in $n$ experiments when $A$ occurs $B$ occurs $m$ times. So observed probability of $B$ given $A$ is $m/n$.
It's obvious that the case when $n = 10, m = 2$ is different from $n = 1000, m = 200$. How can I measure significance of results obtained from observation?

Comment: You would need to explain what you mean by "significance".  One possibility might be to develop [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) which will tend to narrow as your sample size increases

Comment: @Henry, thank you. It seems to be what I need. Will study this and get back